# The Google Earth Engine and GEET packages were used for batch calculation of surface temperature (LST), but error reporting

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I hope to use the GEET package for batch calculation of surface temperature (LST), but there is an error in the calculation of TOA. How can I correct it?

```
var image_col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')

function lst_calc_ls5(image) {
  var toa = geet.toa_radiance(image, 6);
  var ndvi = geet.ndvi_l5(toa);
  var bt = geet.brightness_temp_l5c(ndvi, true);
  var propVeg = geet.prop_veg(bt);
  var lse = geet.surface_emissivity(propVeg);
  var lst = geet.surface_temperature_tm(lse);
  return lst;
}
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(roi),
  ee.Filter.calendarRange(150, 240, 'day_of_year'),
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 30));
var tmCol = image_col.filter(colFilter).map(lst_calc_ls5);
print(tmCol)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a few days ago? I can't find the question now - though it seemed there was no problem. Is this a different issue - please be more specific about your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more complete scripts in your questions, so someone trying to help you doesn't have to guess when filling in blanks, and explain your problem better.

Is it `users/elacerda/geet:geet` you're using? I tried to plug it in to your provided script, and it fails with a:

```
Internal error: function argument not initialized.
    in toa_radiance(), line 855
    ...
```

I looked up the geet [source code](https://github.com/sacridini/GEET/blob/master/geet.js), and noticed that when you specify band 6, it will do a `getInfo()` call. This always fails when you're mapping over a function. If you want to keep on using geet, I suggest you inline `toa_radiance()` into your script and fix it.

```
var roi = Map.getBounds(true)
var geet = require('users/elacerda/geet:geet')

var image_col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')

function lst_calc_ls5(image) {
  var toa = toa_radiance(image, 6)
  var ndvi = geet.ndvi_l5(toa)
  var bt = geet.brightness_temp_l5c(ndvi, true)
  var propVeg = geet.prop_veg(bt)
  var lse = geet.surface_emissivity(propVeg)
  var lst = geet.surface_temperature_tm(lse)
  return lst
}
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(roi),
  ee.Filter.calendarRange(150, 240, 'day_of_year'),
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 30))
var tmCol = image_col.filter(colFilter).map(lst_calc_ls5)
print(tmCol.first())


// From https://github.com/sacridini/GEET/blob/master/geet.js
function toa_radiance(image, band) {
  // Error Handling
  if (image === undefined) error('toa_radiance', 'You need to specify an input image.')
  if (band === undefined) error('toa_radiance', 'You need to specify the number of the band that you want to process.')

  var band_to_toa = image.select('B' + band.toString())
  var radiance_multi_band = ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_' + band.toString())) // Ml
  var radiance_add_band = ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_' + band.toString())) // Al

  // Landsat 7 special case
  // if (band === 6) {
  //   var id = ee.String(image.get('LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID'))
  //   var id_split = id.split("_")
  //   if (ee.String(id_split.get(0)).getInfo() === "LE07") { /*** THIS IS THE PROBLEM ***/
  //     band_to_toa = image.select('B6_VCID_1')
  //     radiance_multi_band = ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6_VCID_1')) // Ml
  //     radiance_add_band = ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_6_VCID_1')) // Al
  //   }
  // }

  var toa_radiance = band_to_toa.expression(
    '(Ml * band) + Al', {
      'Ml': radiance_multi_band,
      'Al': radiance_add_band,
      'band': band_to_toa
    }).rename('TOA_Radiance')
  var img_radiance = image.addBands(toa_radiance)
  return img_radiance
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1651cf2887402560745783d3f7fe2ec7